# How to extract the retweet_count from array using php

Tags: php, twitter

I am using php to find the number of retweets a status has gotten.

this is my current code:

```
//get account info
$connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/statuses/retweets'),
array('id'=> '363332903113351168'));

//get http response code for request
$response_code = $connection->response['code'];

//convert the json response to an array
$response_data = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);

if($code != 200)
{
    print"ERROR: $response_code\n";
}
print_r($response_data);
```

as you can see, this returns a bunch of properties about the retweet. I am trying to get to the retweet_count value. How would I go about doing this?

edit: this is the array of values returned:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => Fri Aug 02 20:34:25 +0000 2013
        [id] => 3.63397397311E+17
        [id_str] => 363397397311135746
        [text] => RT @TAN_DUM: Hello Twitter
        [source] => Twitter for iPhone
        [truncated] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
        [user] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1613117785
                [id_str] => 1613117785
                [name] => //Name
                [screen_name] => //username
                [location] => 
                [description] => 
                [url] => 
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [description] => Array
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [protected] => 
                [followers_count] => 2
                [friends_count] => 5
                [listed_count] => 0
                [created_at] => Mon Jul 22 15:42:46 +0000 2013
                [favourites_count] => 0
                [utc_offset] => -10800
                [time_zone] => Atlantic Time (Canada)
                [geo_enabled] => 
                [verified] => 
                [statuses_count] => 1
                [lang] => en
                [contributors_enabled] => 
                [is_translator] => 
                [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                [profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                [profile_background_tile] => 
                [profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png
                [profile_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png
                [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                [profile_text_color] => 333333
                [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                [default_profile] => 1
                [default_profile_image] => 1
                [following] => 
                [follow_request_sent] => 
                [notifications] => 
            )

        [geo] => 
        [coordinates] => 
        [place] => 
        [contributors] => 
        [retweeted_status] => Array
            (
                [created_at] => Fri Aug 02 16:18:09 +0000 2013
                [id] => 3.63332903113E+17
                [id_str] => 363332903113351168
                [text] => Hello Twitter
                [source] => Tandum
                [truncated] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1638167988
                        [id_str] => 1638167988
                        [name] => Tandum
                        [screen_name] => TAN_DUM
                        [location] => 
                        [description] => 
                        [url] => 
                        [entities] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Array
                                    (
                                        [urls] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [protected] => 
                        [followers_count] => 0
                        [friends_count] => 0
                        [listed_count] => 0
                        [created_at] => Thu Aug 01 15:14:27 +0000 2013
                        [favourites_count] => 0
                        [utc_offset] => -10800
                        [time_zone] => Atlantic Time (Canada)
                        [geo_enabled] => 
                        [verified] => 
                        [statuses_count] => 2
                        [lang] => en
                        [contributors_enabled] => 
                        [is_translator] => 
                        [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                        [profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                        [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                        [profile_background_tile] => 
                        [profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png
                        [profile_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png
                        [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                        [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                        [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                        [profile_text_color] => 333333
                        [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                        [default_profile] => 1
                        [default_profile_image] => 1
                        [following] => 
                        [follow_request_sent] => 
                        [notifications] => 
                    )

                [geo] => 
                [coordinates] => 
                [place] => 
                [contributors] => 
                [retweet_count] => 1
                [favorite_count] => 0
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [hashtags] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [symbols] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [urls] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [user_mentions] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [favorited] => 
                [retweeted] => 
                [lang] => no
            )

        [retweet_count] => 1
        [favorite_count] => 0
        [entities] => Array
            (
                [hashtags] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [symbols] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [urls] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [user_mentions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [screen_name] => TAN_DUM
                                [name] => Tandum
                                [id] => 1638167988
                                [id_str] => 1638167988
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 3
                                        [1] => 11
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [favorited] => 
        [retweeted] => 
        [lang] => no
    )
```

)

Comment: Can you post the JSON received ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work?

```
$retweet_count = $response_data[0]['retweet_count'];
```

Comment: yeah, that works. I actually figured it out but I couldn't answer my own question. I used a foreach loop to run through every value and then return the value: $value['retweet_count'];

Comment: @user2635015: You can actually answer your own question http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer